# php serialized data back to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, serialization

I thought i did something smart when i serialize($userinfo) and saved the serialized data in my db... $userinfo is a plain array. but how do i get a hold of the data so my javascript can use it?

tried

```
var userinfo = <?=unserialize(GetUserInfo(userId));?>;
```

GetUserInfo is a global function that fetches the serialized string from the db.

Comment: question is unclear?? please explain, may b this [article]( https://gist.github.com/242617) helps u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var userinfo = <?php json_encode(GetUserInfo($user_id));?>;
```

JavaScript doesn't understand serialized PHP data but it does understand JSON as that is formated as a regular JavaScript object.

Comment: Make sure to utf8 encode al the data you pass into json_encode, since it only handles utf8. On an english website you might not notice, since all un-accented latin letters are the same in iso8859-1 and utf8, but it will stop working as soon as anyone enters an "ä", "ç" or "ฒ".